# ImageView android abort program

Tags: android, imageview

I am programming a android app with `ImageView` and when I try to change the width and height dynamically, the app stops (abort). I am using the following commands:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams icon_horizontal = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
mec21h_icon2.setLayoutParams(icon_horizontal);
```

The layout is Relative, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have a Stack trace in order to understand what the error is.
Without this, I can just guess:

- you're trying to use the wrong parent layout params
- the ImageView ref is null
- ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to change the image dimensions after it is visible (already  displayed), if so you should first call for method requestLayout();
i.e.

```
       mImageView.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-size image on Click of a button.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    tools:context="com.testingpp.scannerbarcode.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="button_one"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_back"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FrameLayout layout;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView  =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);

    }

    public void button_one(View view)
    {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

   }
```

if you are using Framents, then don't use onClick of xml. use onClickListener in java.